# Spring security dynamic Role permission role and permission not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am implementing a spring security with roles and permission which i fetch from database. It works fine in the case of mapped url only. For unmapped url i an not getting 403. Below is my http configuration. Any help appreciated.

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfigure extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
  }

@Override
      public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    
        List<Role> roleModules = roleActionRepository.findAll();
    
        ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry urlRegistry = httpSecurity.authorizeRequests();
    
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable();
        
        urlRegistry.antMatchers(
          "/authenticate",
          "/public/**",
          "/common/**"
        ).permitAll();
        
        roleModules.forEach(roleAction -> {
          urlRegistry.antMatchers(HttpMethod.valueOf(module.getType()), module.getName()).hasAuthority(roleAction.getName());
        });
    
        urlRegistry.anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().csrf().disable().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
      }
@Bean
  @Override
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }
}
```

Lets say i have one url mapping /employee/** which i get from database. For that my code works fine.
But lets say i have another url like /user/** which is not configured for any role. So ideally on one can access that end point. But i am able to access that point without role assign. So how i can prevent this thing.

You can also find out the screen shot of the role mapping

[image]

when ever the `urlRegistry.anyRequest().authenticated()` called the 4th indenxing is added.

Comment: yes its called at the application initialization time

Comment: yes url is not in list. i am using jwt so by role  i am allowing user to access the resource url

Comment: i have checked all the mapping. There is nothing related to wild card mapping

Comment: some how permitAll url working other than all url is treated as white listed

Comment: I have debugging any ways and found that any thing configured with urlRegistry is not working. So do I need to do extra configuration to call the or i have to assign it with http security object?